# A coalgebra structure on compact operators

Tags: matrices, oa.operator-algebras, coalgebras

> Is there a  coalgebra  structure $\Delta_{n}$ on $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ which is  compatible  with the  natural  embedding $i_{n:}M_{n}(\mathbb{C})\to M_{n+1}(\mathbb{C})$  with    $i_{n}(A)= A\oplus 0$. That is $(i_{n}\otimes i_{n})\circ \Delta_{n}=\Delta_{n+1}\circ i_{n}$.

If the answer is yes, can this  method be used to equip the  space  of  compact  operators, the (topological)  direct limit of  $M_{n}(\mathbb{C}),s$,   with  a coalgebraic  structure?

Comment: Just to clarify: when you pass to the "limit" and look at $K(\ell_2)$, would you be satisfied with a comultiplication that took values in some *completion* of the usual tensor product, such as the spatial tensor product $K(\ell_2)\overline{\otimes} K(\ell_2)$?

Comment: @YemonChoi Very interesting point. However the usual definition of coalgebra requires the  comultiplication took value in the  algebraic tensor product, but your interesting comment is  a  motivation to  ask about  calgebraic structure on $C^{*}$  algebras with comultiplication in $A\bar{\otimes} A$. Is there some standard definition on this  generalized coalgebraic  structure? Any  way both algebraic  and  topological comultiplication values  are interesting.

Comment: And  after a reasonable coalgebraic  structure on compact operators the  next  question would  be  about  **closed** coideals  and cosubalgebras. Is it  a  cosimple  coalgebra?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $V$ finite-dimensional, the algebra $\hom(V, V) \cong V^\ast \otimes V$ is naturally self-dual, and this duality may be used to transfer an algebra structure on $\hom(V, V)$ to a coalgebra structure on $\hom(V, V)$, and vice-versa. (Notice that the duality functor $\text{Vect}^{op} \to \text{Vect}$ on finite-dimensional spaces induces a functor from coalgebras to algebras, and vice-versa.)

The map $M_n(\mathbb{C}) \to M_{n+1}(\mathbb{C})$ mapping $A \mapsto A \oplus 0$ is dual to the map $M_{n+1}(\mathbb{C}) \to M_n(\mathbb{C})$ that takes an $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ matrix to the $n \times n$ matrix made from the first $n$ rows and columns. If we choose the algebra structure on the spaces $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ to be not the usual matrix multiplication but the one given by entrywise multiplication, then these are algebra maps and they dualize to coalgebra maps. This gives an affirmative answer to the question. However, this is clearly highly dependent on basis and doesn't strike me as terribly interesting.

The forgetful functor $\text{Coalg} \to \text{Vect}$ creates colimits, and so the colimit of a chain of coalgebra maps $M_n(\mathbb{C}) \to M_{n+1}(\mathbb{C})$ is created from the colimit in $\text{Vect}$. This answers the second question affirmatively.

Comment: thank you for your interesting  answer. Could  you please explain how  we extend the  comultiplication to the  space  of  compact operators(The  closure of  the  algebraic direct limit)?

Comment: Ali's recent edit inserted the word "topological", which might introduce some delicacy since there are various tensor products one might consider on TVS. But for any symmetric monoidal category $M$, the forgetful functor $\text{Coalg}(M) \to M$ still creates colimits.

Comment: could  you please more explain on your last comment? and  also your extension of  comultiplication to the space  of  compact operators?

Comment: @AliTaghavi Keeping in mind that I am not a functional analyst, the coalgebra comultiplication $\text{colim}\; M_n \to (\text{colim}\; M_n) \otimes (\text{colim}\; M_n)$ would be induced (via the universal property of colimits) from the cocone $M_n \to M_n \otimes M_n \to (\text{colim}\; M_n) \otimes (\text{colim}\; M_n)$ where $M_n \to \text{colim}\; M_n$ is the canonical inclusion. Here colimits = direct limits would be computed in a suitable TVS sense. Does that help?

Comment: Todd, if we work in the symmetric monoidal category Bang of Banach spaces and maps of norm at most 1, then doesn't one have to tweak your initial remarks about hom(V,V) being self-dual? It seems one would need to do a bit more work to create a coalgebra structure on ${\rm End}_{\rm Bang}(\ell_2^n)$ a.k.a. $M_n({\bf C})$ with its usual norm. But perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: @YemonChoi Yes, I think you are probably right. I composed my answer ignoring the topological aspects, which were brought more forcefully to attention by Ali's edit. So what he is *really* after no doubt deserves more attention.